# Mask Some Part of ID before displaying in email

Tags: sql, vb.net, ssis

My SSIS package is creating a automated email for records which are failed or having any error in the record, it will generate a email template with following details.

```
Public Shared Sub AddErrorDetail(ByRef sbErrorLst As List(Of ErrorDetail), ByVal ErrorMsg As String, ByVal ErrorLevel As String, Optional ByVal node As XmlNode = Nothing, Optional ByVal paycheckNode As XmlNode = Nothing, Optional ByVal paycheckDetailNode As XmlNode = Nothing, Optional ByVal ddNode As XmlNode = Nothing)
    Dim sErrorDetail As New ErrorDetail
    sErrorDetail.ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg
    sErrorDetail.ErrorLevel = ErrorLevel
    Try
        If node IsNot Nothing Then
            If node("EmpID") IsNot Nothing Then
                sErrorDetail.EmpID = node("EmpID").InnerText
            End If
        End If

        If Not paycheckNode Is Nothing Then
            If Not paycheckNode("DocumentID") Is Nothing Then
                sErrorDetail.DocumentID = paycheckNode("DocumentID").InnerText
            End If
    sbErrorLst.Add(sErrorDetail)
    Catch ex As Exception
        sErrorDetail.ErrorMsg = ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace
        sErrorDetail.ErrorLevel = "High"
        sErrorDetail.FunctionID = "AddErrorDetail"
        sErrorDetail.ErrorNbr = "-102"
        sbErrorLst.Add(sErrorDetail)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I dont want to display total EmpID in the mail for example if EmpID is 123456789 i just want to show 12#####89 
how can i do it in vb.net script. in above code

Looking for help Thanks

Comment: Are EmpIDs fixed-length?

Comment: yes it is always 9 digit number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly is your rule but this can be done with substring.

```
    Dim id As String = "123456789"
    Dim result As String

    result = id.Substring(0, 2).PadRight(id.Length - 2, "#") & id.Substring(id.Length - 2)
```

If you want an example on how to use it with your code. I would suggest making a function.

```
Function ShowPartialId(ByVal id As String)
    Return id.Substring(0, 2).PadRight(id.Length - 2, "#") & id.Substring(id.Length - 2)
End Function
```

And then you just need to call the function

```
sErrorDetail.EmpID = ShowPartialId(node("EmpID").InnerText)
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i use it in above code.

Comment: @user3494425 Just put the piece of code I provided in a function and call that function on your string. I don't have the full code with me so I can only speculate on what is needed to do. It's up to you to figure it out.